# Paypal IPN Cancel Membership PHP

Tags: php, mysql, paypal, paypal-ipn

So the code that I've got for when a user purchases membership works perfectly. However I'm unsure how to code if for when the user cancels. What fields do papal throw at you when the user cancels through them?

I understand I'm supposed to use `subscr_cancelled` but am unsure the correct psuedocode and logic behind the cancellation.

For example:

- What is the payment status when the user cancels?
- Do I just ignore payment status?

Here's my code thus far, its a little clunky as i've been testing a lot:

```
if (strcmp ($res, "VERIFIED") == 0) {
    // check whether the payment_status is Completed
    // check that txn_id has not been previously processed
    // check that receiver_email is your PayPal email
    // check that payment_amount/payment_currency are correct
    // process payment and mark item as paid.
    // assign posted variables to local variables

    $item_name = $_POST['item_name'];
    $item_number = $_POST['item_number'];
    $txn_type = $_POST['txn_type'];
    $payment_status = $_POST['payment_status'];
    $payment_amount = $_POST['mc_gross'];
    $payment_currency = $_POST['mc_currency'];
    $txn_id = $_POST['txn_id'];
    $receiver_email = $_POST['receiver_email'];
    $payer_email = $_POST['payer_email'];
    $id = $_POST['custom'];
    $make_premium =1;
    $make_loser=0;


        if($payment_status=="Completed"){
        $user_id_check = $mysqli->query("SELECT `username` FROM `users` WHERE `ID` ='$id'");
        if($user_id_check->num_rows > 0){
            $txn_id_check = $mysqli->query("SELECT `transaction_id` FROM `payment` WHERE `transaction_id`='$txn_id'");
            if($txn_id_check->num_rows != 1) {  
                        $query = "INSERT INTO `payment` (`transaction_id`, `payment_status`, `users_id`, `txn_type`) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?)";
                        $statement = $mysqli->prepare($query);
                        $statement->bind_param('ssis',$txn_id, $payment_status, $id, $txn_type);
                        if($statement->execute()){
                            if($txn_type =="subscr_signup"){
                                $update_user_to_premium =("UPDATE `users` SET `is_member` =? WHERE `ID` =?");
                                $stmt =$mysqli->prepare($update_user_to_premium);
                                $stmt->bind_param('ii',$make_premium,$id);
                                $stmt->execute();
                            }
                        }else{
                        die('Error : ('. $mysqli->errno .') '. $mysqli->error);
                        }
                        $statement->close();
               }
            }
        }
    }
    if($txn_id_check->num_rows == 1){
        if($txn_type=="subscr_cancel"){
            $update_user_to_loser =("UPDATE `users` SET `is_member` =? WHERE `ID` =?");
            $stmt =$mysqli->prepare($update_user_to_loser);
            $stmt->bind_param('ii',$make_loser,$id);
            $stmt->execute();
        }
    {
    if(DEBUG == true) {
        error_log(date('[Y-m-d H:i e] '). "Verified IPN: $req ". PHP_EOL, 3, LOG_FILE);
    }
} else if (strcmp ($res, "INVALID") == 0) {
    // log for manual investigation
    // Add business logic here which deals with invalid IPN messages
    if(DEBUG == true) {
        error_log(date('[Y-m-d H:i e] '). "Invalid IPN: $req" . PHP_EOL, 3, LOG_FILE);
    }
}
```

Should I be using something like this

```
switch ($_POST['txn_type']) {   
 case 'subscr_signup':
        break;

    case 'subscr_eot':
       //subscription end of term
        break;

    case 'subscr_cancel':
        //subscription canceled
        break;
```

**EDIT:**

```
if (strcmp ($res, "VERIFIED") == 0) {
    // check whether the payment_status is Completed
    // check that txn_id has not been previously processed
    // check that receiver_email is your PayPal email
    // check that payment_amount/payment_currency are correct
    // process payment and mark item as paid.
    // assign posted variables to local variables

    $item_name = $_POST['item_name'];
    $item_number = $_POST['item_number'];
    $txn_type = $_POST['txn_type'];
    $payment_status = $_POST['payment_status'];
    $payment_amount = $_POST['mc_gross'];
    $payment_currency = $_POST['mc_currency'];
    $txn_id = $_POST['txn_id'];
    $receiver_email = $_POST['receiver_email'];
    $payer_email = $_POST['payer_email'];
    $id = $_POST['custom'];
    $subscr_id = $_POST['subscr_id'];
    $make_premium =1;
    $make_loser=0;


        if($payment_status=="Completed"){
        $user_id_check = $mysqli->query("SELECT `username` FROM `users` WHERE `ID` ='$id'");
        if($user_id_check->num_rows > 0){
            $txn_id_check = $mysqli->query("SELECT `transaction_id` FROM `payment` WHERE `transaction_id`='$txn_id'");
            if($txn_id_check->num_rows != 1) {  
                        $query = "INSERT INTO `payment` (`transaction_id`, `payment_status`, `users_id`, `txn_type`, `subscr_id`) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
                        $statement = $mysqli->prepare($query);
                        $statement->bind_param('ssiss',$txn_id, $payment_status, $id, $txn_type, $subscr_id);
                        if($statement->execute()){
                            if($txn_type =="subscr_signup"){
                                $update_user_to_premium =("UPDATE `users` SET `is_member` =? WHERE `ID` =?");
                                $stmt =$mysqli->prepare($update_user_to_premium);
                                $stmt->bind_param('ii',$make_premium,$id);
                                $stmt->execute();
                            }
                        }else{
                        die('Error : ('. $mysqli->errno .') '. $mysqli->error);
                        }
                        $statement->close();
               }
            }
        }
    }

        if($txn_type=="subscr_cancel"){
            // get user id from row with subscription id 
            $get_user_id = $mysqli->("SELECT `users_id` FROM `payment` WHERE `subscr_id`='$subscr_id'");
            $row = $get_user_id->fetch_assoc();
            $users_id = $row[`users_id`];
            $update_user_to_loser =("UPDATE `users` SET `is_member` =? WHERE `ID` =?");
            $stmt =$mysqli->prepare($update_user_to_loser);
            $stmt->bind_param('ii',$make_loser,$users_id);
            $stmt->execute();
        }
    {
    if(DEBUG == true) {
        error_log(date('[Y-m-d H:i e] '). "Verified IPN: $req ". PHP_EOL, 3, LOG_FILE);
    }
} else if (strcmp ($res, "INVALID") == 0) {
    // log for manual investigation
    // Add business logic here which deals with invalid IPN messages
    if(DEBUG == true) {
        error_log(date('[Y-m-d H:i e] '). "Invalid IPN: $req" . PHP_EOL, 3, LOG_FILE);
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Why won't you use the [IPN simulator](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNSimulator/)?

Comment: Because the IPN simulator doesn't account for recurring memberships. I have tested with the IPN simulator for days! @Alon It also doesn't account for cancellations etc.

Comment: Do I have to take into consideration subscr_id? I really wish there was more documentation on this for recurring payments @AndrewAngell

Comment: I moved my original comment to an answer with more details.  As for the subscr_id, that's up to you.  You can do whatever you want/need to do with the IPN data that gets sent, but based on the type of transaction that is processed (payment, refund, subscription signup/payment/cancel, etc.) you may or may not have particular parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a profile is canceled then there is no payment taking place. That's a different type of transaction. There is no payment, so there is no payment status, so you won't get that parameter in that sort of an IPN.

You can easily test this in the sandbox.  You just need to create a seller account and a buyer account, and configure IPN in your seller account to hit your listener.  Then create a subscription button from the seller account, sign up from the buyer account, and then cancel it.  That will trigger IPNs for each step so you can see what to expect and adjust your IPN listener accordingly.

Here is an example of an IPN for a subscr_cancel transaction.

```
Array
(
    [amount3] => 4.99
    [address_status] => confirmed
    [recur_times] => 2
    [subscr_date] => 15:51:33 Jan 19, 2015 PST
    [payer_id] => YW66KXBKJRRES
    [address_street] => 123 Test Ave
    [mc_amount3] => 4.99
    [charset] => windows-1252
    [address_zip] => 64030
    [first_name] => Tester
    [reattempt] => 1
    [address_country_code] => US
    [address_name] => Testers, LLC
    [notify_version] => 3.8
    [subscr_id] => S-6YS75493RP123324L
    [payer_status] => verified
    [business] => sandbo_1215254764_biz@angelleye.com
    [address_country] => United States
    [address_city] => Grandview
    [verify_sign] => AI7Wj0s667jdpY.UclGpjUpSpsZNAJzn.UcYbCVhXVG5fO05tyBo36EL
    [payer_email] => drew@angelleye.com
    [payer_business_name] => Testers, LLC
    [last_name] => Testerson
    [address_state] => MO
    [receiver_email] => sandbo_1215254764_biz@angelleye.com
    [recurring] => 1
    [txn_type] => subscr_cancel
    [item_name] => Test Subscription
    [mc_currency] => USD
    [item_number] => TEST-123
    [residence_country] => US
    [test_ipn] => 1
    [period3] => 1 M
    [ipn_track_id] => f0f2f2be88fd
)
```

Comment: So the way I've laid it out is correct? By not putting the subscr_cancelled in the payment_status if statement? Plus should I be storing info when the user cancels their membership or should I just update them to a non member? Plus surely I need to take into consideration the subscr_id in order to update the user to non premium ?

Comment: The value for txn_type would not be subscr_cancelled, it would be subscr_cancel

Comment: The first one is correctly using subscr_cancel but the second one is still showing subscr_cancelled

Comment: oh yeah sorry thats not what I'm asking. Am I using the correct logic for this? is this the way I should be approaching the problem?

Comment: That depends on what your goal is, but yes, you would keep your code that runs when a subscription is canceled within that if/then logic.  You just need to make sure you're using the correct value.

Comment: Guess all I need to do now is test it, thank you @AndrewAngell